# sympy: How to get zero for absent constant term

Tags: python, sympy, coefficients

On  SymPy 0.7.5 (Python 2.7.8-64-bit). I'm unable to get the constant term from an expression when the constant term is zero or absent (an absent constant is the same of a zero constant, right?).

I can get the constant term from an expression with `expr.coeff(x, 0)`. E.g.:

```
isympy ## Load sympy etc...

(x + 3).coeff(x, 0)        #-> 3 ok
(x).coeff(x, 0)            #-> 0 ok
(4*x**2 + 3*x).coeff(x, 0) #-> 0 ok
```

Now, how can I get 0 in these cases?

```
(4*x).coeff(x, 0)     #-> 4 
(4*x**2).coeff(x, 0)  #-> 4 why not 0?!
```

I'm sure this has been asked & documented before but I can't find the answer at least without some awkward workaround.
Thanks
Dario

*Edit* Full output from interactive session:

```
python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 14 2014, 18:20:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import sympy
>>> 
>>> x= sympy.symbols('x')
>>> (4*x).coeff(x, 0)
4
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.5'
```

Comment: Well its giving me 0 ... `
>>> (4*x**2).coeff(x, 0) prints 
0
`

Comment: @maandoo - Interesting. It doesn't work for me. See edit. Would you mind posting your version of python and sympy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Upgrade to sympy 0.7.6. Unless I was doing something silly it appears this was a bug 0.7.5.

```
python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 14 2014, 18:20:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sympy
>>> x= sympy.symbols('x')
>>> (4*x).coeff(x, 0)
0
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, from memory, quite compatibly, something like
(4*x + 3*y + 7).coeff(x, 0)
gives
3*y + 7
.
Have yet to discover an elegant way to get the constant term.